# $http get response data issue when saving to a scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Below is the code that has some issue in assigning return values to the scope variable.

```
app.factory("appService",function($http){
  var promise;
  var lists = {
    async: function() {
      var promise = $http.get("http://localhost:81/hrms/public/languagesService").then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
      });
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return lists;
});
```

The response from the `$http` get is successful with status code 200. Below is the code, using the above service in the controller

```
app.controller("AppCtrl",function(appService,$scope,$http,$filter) {
  $scope.language = "";

  var sortingOrder = 'id';
  $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
  $scope.reverse = false;
  $scope.filteredItems = [];
  $scope.groupedItems = [];
  $scope.itemsPerPage = 4;
  $scope.pagedItems = [];
  $scope.currentPage = 0;
  $scope.items = [];


  $scope.itemlist = function() {

    appService.async().then(function(d){
      $scope.data = d;
    });

  }

  $scope.items = $scope.itemlist();
```

But the `$scope.items` is empty. please guide me how to pass values to `$scope.items`. i have also tried `$scope.items.push(d)`, but nothing seems to work...

All i want is to have `$scope.items` to hold the response data from `$http.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the response is array. So you can return empty array, and then fill it with data, after response will be delivered:

```
$scope.itemlist = function() {
   var result = [];
   appService.async().then(function(d){
      $scope.data = d;
      result.push.apply(result,d);
   });
   return result;
};

$scope.items = $scope.itemlist();
```

Here we use `apply` method to `push` multiple elements at once.

Comment: @uma Make sure that `d` is array.

Comment: response is coming in json format. Content-Type application/json.

Comment: @uma Is response an array?

Comment: actually, i want the scope.items to be passed to the, but the value being passed is null.                   $scope.search = function () {
        $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
            for(var attr in item) {
                if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

Comment: @uma I did get, that the data is in json format. But what is it? Object? Array? String? Can you write any response sample in your question post?

Comment: thanks for your support. The output actually was object. i sorted out the issue, by actually moving $scope.filteredItems into the appService.async().then(function(d){}.

Answer (score 0):

Hi why don't you just assign d to $scope.items as follows

```
app.controller("AppCtrl",function(appService,$scope,$http,$filter) {
  $scope.language = "";

  var sortingOrder = 'id';
  $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
  $scope.reverse = false;
  $scope.filteredItems = [];
  $scope.groupedItems = [];
  $scope.itemsPerPage = 4;
  $scope.pagedItems = [];
  $scope.currentPage = 0;
  $scope.items = [];

  appService.async().then(function(d){
      $scope.items = d;
    });
})
```